# Can I change the sorting of my files and directories in a TextMate project?

Tags: macos, textmate

I'd really love the ability to sort my directories ahead of my files, but I'm not sure if that's possible. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available through the [Project Plus plugin](https://github.com/ciaran/projectplus/). It is generally a big improvement over TextMate's default project pane.